# preg_replace keywords OUTSIDE of <strong> tags

Tags: php, regex

I can't tell you guys how many hours I've spent on this one. I simply want to *IGNORE* any instances of keywords that are *BETWEEN* the strong tags. Whether they are directly next to the tags or somewhere in between with other words. All while keeping the keywords case-insensitive.

Example:

```
The man drove in his car. Then <strong>the man walked to the boat.</strong>
```

The word `boat` should be ignored and `Car` should be replaced.

```
$keywords = array(
'boat',
'car',
);

$p = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords));

$string = preg_replace("/\b($p)\b/i", 'gokart', $string, 4);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [SKIP-FAIL regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) for to only replace something that is clearly outside on non-identical delimiters:

```
<strong>.*?<\/strong>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(boat|car)\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG1fC6/4)

Here is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0kvEA6):

```
$str = "The man drove in his car.Then <strong>the man walked to the boat.</strong>"; 
$keywords = array('boat','car');
$p = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $keywords));
$result = preg_replace("#<strong>.*?<\/strong>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b($p)\b#i", "gokart", $str);
echo $result;
```

**NOTE** that in this case, we most probably are not interested in a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) solution inside the SKIP-FAIL block (that I posted initially, see revision history) since we do not care what is in between the delimiters.

Comment: Can you please provide some information on the `SKIP` and `FAIL`?

Comment: @npinti: I added the link to the answer, `SKIP-FAIL` regex "trick" (no magic implied :)) has been this spring hit on some days.

Comment: I think everyone agrees that regular expressions are close to sorcery, you even have good and evil :P. Thanks for the link, very informative.

Comment: I came across SKIP/FAIL in my decades of research over this. I even attempted it, (improperly ofcourse). I will read more into it and hopefully learn more on regex.

Anyway, your answer works great. Answer Accepted. If its any consolation, you will literally help someone sleep better tonight. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is probably not the best way to do something like this.

It would probably be best to use a DOM parser or something similar to properly find the `<strong>` tags.

A few of the answers here offer some good options: [RegEx: Matching text that is not inside and part of a HTML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970743/regex-matching-text-that-is-not-inside-and-part-of-a-html-tag)

Comment: The question you provide a link to is not about *replacing* the text, but *matching*. and there is no answer to the OP question.

Comment: Yes, but a PHP `preg_replace` does a replace on **matches**. So very relevant.